# Docker Swarm bringing up containers after node is down only after 1 minute

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, swarm

I'm testing Docker Swarm behavior for case when one Swarm Node is down.

And I've see that Docker Swarm start bringing up containers from failed node only after 50-60 seconds which is quite long from my point of view. Containers themselves starting quite fast.

So, is it possible to tune Swarm somehow to decrease this time when Swarm figured out that node is down and it's needed to start new containers?

Comment: Please provide more details about your container & host ; I cannot guess even where or what to check.

Comment: Check container logs for errors that might be occuring in the app that's deployed.